# Scoping sessions to a particular section of a Coldfusion application?

Tags: session, coldfusion

Is there a way to enable sessions for just a specific part of the Coldfusion application by just adding Application.cfm into its directory with the session enablers?

For example, a website that has the following:

- /extranet
- /intranet
- /store
- /rentals

I want to use session variables in the rental section, independent of the ones in the intranet and store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't *want* to share session variables, and don't *need* to share application variables, then it's easy. Just put a different Application.cfc (or .cfm) in the root of the context for which you want access to the session variables.

So if you want sessions in /extranet, and sessions in /intranet and don't want them to be the same application, then:

/extranet/Application.cfc:

```
component {
    this.name = "extranet";
    this.sessionmanagement = true;
}
```

/intranet/Application.cfc:

```
component {
    this.name = "intranet";
    this.sessionmanagement = true;
}
```

It sounds like you aren't really up to speed on all of the things that you can do with Application.cfc, so I'll also add that [this is a really good reference](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/726-ColdFusion-Application-cfc-Tutorial-And-Application-cfc-Reference.htm). There is a lot to learn, but it is also pretty simple once you understand how it works.

Comment: It's been a long time since I have used any of this. What I want to do is have a session ID ready to use and store in a struct when someone tries to book a property, so I can pass the struct data on to a web service invocation, then clear the struct. Just need a way to know on each page who is who and how to access their session/struct. Do I need to do all of this in the referenced page?

Comment: I don't really follow, sorry. Can you talk a little bit less in abstract terms? Perhaps update the question with more specific information.

Comment: Looks like a higher level Application.cfm was interfering with my efforts. Should I just use cfcookie instead? The CF docs say to not use struct functions against session variables. Any weight to that?

Comment: I'm guessing the recommendation you saw was not to use structClear() on the session scope; and the reason is that it not only removes anything you might have put into the session, but also the session token(s). There is no reason you can't use structDelete(), structKeyExists(), etc with the session scope. As for whether cookies would be a better approach to what you're trying to do, I can't say, because you still haven't explained your goal clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a Single Signon (SSO) solution would work for you? Rather than monkey around with the values in the session struct, just pass a user id from one app to another. When the user passes from extranet to rentals, the app says "here comes user #45", the rentals app looks them up in the db, does some validation to make sure that the user is who the extranet says they are, then starts a new session for them in rentals.